# Strange behavior of PowerShell matching against array string element

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I'm quite desperate for tips here. Here's my quandary:

First, I had an array of string, which I created this way (showing a subset of the numbers):

```
$a = @"
00013120747
00013051436
00013110491
00002100011
"@

$aa = $a.Split("`n")
```

Next, I generate a list of all users in Active Directory (using ActiveRoles) this way:

```
$all_u = Get-QADUser -DontUseDefaultIncludedProperties -IncludedProperties Name,LogonName,EmployeeID -SizeLimit 0
```

Now, why can't I match against an element of the `$aa` array? For example, doing the following:

```
$all_u | where {$_.EmployeeID -match "00013110491"}
```

it works. But if I do the following:

```
$all_u | where {$_.EmployeeID -match $aa[2]}
```

it doesn't work.

So I did a simpler test:

```
$aa.GetType().Name
String[]

$aa[2].GetType().Name
String

$aa[2]
00013110491

$aa[2] -eq "00013110491"
False
```

What?? What's going on here???

I'm using PowerShell ISE, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you examine the elements of $aa carefully, you'll find they all have trailing whitespace.  This is a consequence of doing the split on "`n".  If you trim them after you do the split, you'll get the expected result.

```
$a = @"
00013120747
00013051436
00013110491
00002100011
"@

$aa = $a.Split("`n") |% {$_.trim()}

$aa[2] -eq "00013110491"

True
```

The -match will match anywhere in the string, so it will still match even with the trailing space.  The -eq requires and exact match, character for character, and the trailing space will cause it to return False.

Comment: Whoa, nice find! I actually tried `foreach ($elem in $aa) { "=={0}==" -f $elem }` and each line doesn't show any trailing space. Thanks for telling me! Marking yours as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = @"
00013120747
00013051436
00013110491
00002100011
"@

$aa = $a.Split("`r`n")
```

Answer (score -2):

You're using a here string.  That syntax like this:

```
$String = @"
entry1
entry2
entry3
"@

$String.Count
 >1
```

You need to Split your here string first before you can compare them.  If you look at what you actually get when you run

```
 $a[2]
 > '0'
```

You're asking PowerShell for the 2nd index position.  That means this. 00[0]13120747

This is because a here-string is a single string, which that happens to contain multiple lines.  With PowerShell array indexing, if there is only one single entry, you'll get back that position from the list.

```
$string = "0123456"
$string[0..2]
 >012
```

Comment: Didn't you see that I have done exactly that? $aa = $a.Split("`n")

Comment: I missed that.  It looks like Mjolinor was correct here, this seems to be an error in the ISE, injecting a space in the end of every character.  Checking the length of each entry, they are twelve chars long in the ISE, vs 11 when working in the Console.